# JFace + SWT Composite table viewer

Tags: swt, jface, composite, tableviewer

I got Error When I try creating a composite table column?

Error is:
Error Come Arrayindexout of Bound:
[image: Error Come Arrayindexout of Bound image1]

Application does not start when I take Composite:
[image: Application does not start when I take Composite image2]

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.TableColumnLayout;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.IMemento;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

 public class Theartview extends ViewPart implements Serializable {

   public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
    tableComposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
    tableComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
            true));
  }
 }
```

Comment: ViewPart mean this is an Eclipse plugin possibly in an RCP not just SWT + JFace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code is doing is setting up the layout for the table using `TableColumnLayout`. You have done nothing to actually create the table that this layout will manage. When you run the code in this state it crashes because it cannot find the table.

So you must add code to create the `TableViewer`, at a minimum this might be something like:

```java
Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
tableComposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
tableComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(tableComposite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
// TODO viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
viewer.setInput(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

I have just shown a simple `setInput` here, you will need to change this. You will also probably have to define a label provider.

This very simple table is not using columns. You need to define columns using `TableViewerColumn` to make full use of this layout.

**Note:** `ViewPart` is an Eclipse view in a plugin (which might be part of a standalone RCP). It is not a plain JFace + SWT application.